# Intuitive Picture for a Spin Density Wave (SDW)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, quantum-spin

I know that there might be several similar questions concerning this topic, but nevertheless there is one thing I don't get:

What exactly is a SDW? And is there an intuitive picture / cartoon-like model for that? I can't find it in the standard text book literature (Ashcroft etc.), or am I wrong?

Comment: A spin density wave is when the spins in the system have some long range order. For example, an anti-ferromagnet has an alternating order of spins pointing up and down. There are more complex versions as well, such as a spin pointing up on every third site, etc.